# Within MongoDB aggregate pipeline, match between fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have part of aggregate pipeline that is using that code that is working

```
$expr: {$in: ["$myCompanyBidsData._id", "$bestCompanyBids._id"]},
```

I want fetch data that the `_id` of `myCompanyBidsDat`a that wont match `_id` of one of the object in the `listbestCompanyBids`.

I have tried to use `$nin`, not inside/outside the `$expr`, but its not working.

Comment: Would be great if you can share the sample document. Thanks.\

Comment: Try: `$expr: {$not: {$in: ["$myCompanyBidsData._id", "$bestCompanyBids._id"]}}`

Answer (score 0):

try this. i could not give a more complete answer without seeing the query.

```
{
  $match: {
     $expr: {
         $not: {
             $in: ["$myCompanyBidsData._id", "$bestCompanyBids._id"]
         }
     }
  }
}
```